# Торговые предложения со свойствами типа строка/список

Tags: 1с, битрикс

Добрый день!
Столкнулся с проблемой, сымитировал её на сайте "из коробки". В инфоблоке торговых предложений создал свойство типа "строка" (назвал "Цвет (new)"), создал товар с предложениями, завёл несколько предложений с разным значением этого свойства и разной ценой http://joxi.ru/Iqg7VIwyTJDwbpZJXyc . Но в карточке товара выбрать "Цвет (new)" не могу http://joxi.ru/Yqg7VIwyTJCGeZp_Yvs , у меня просто показывает Цвет (new) Чёрный и всё. Количественный учёт включен, всех ТП по 1000 шт., складской учёт выключен.

Кто знает, в чём дело? Где теперь подсмотреть, как делать выбор и добавление ТП в корзину?

P.S. У меня почти сайт готов, сделал на него выгрузку из 1С с предварительным разбиением характеристик товара на отдельные свойства (тут где-то в блоге описывается механизм этот). Так вот, характеристики там разбились на свойства типа "строка", и ТП не работают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось, 1С Битрикс немного изменил правила работы с торговыми предложениями: http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=42&LESSON_ID=3155

Теперь торговые предложения могут выполняться **только** по свойствам типа **Список** и **Справочник**. Переделал скрипт, перезалил данные, и всё заработало.

Comment: Какой скрипт? куда перезалили? почему нельзя сразу с конкретикой. у нас сейчас такая же проблема.

Comment: Скрипт в init.php раньше до появления модуля обмена от битрикса в init.php писали скрипт который перехватывал данные пришедшие из 1С  и рассовывал их по нужным свойствам. Сейчас этого делать не нужно, всё можно настроить в модуле обмена 1С Битрикс http://1c.1c-bitrix.ru/ecommerce/download.php (мануал как поставить и настроить http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=42&LESSON_ID=7184&LESSON_PATH=3912.4912.7184 ) Если всё таки хотите без модуля  то скрипт выглядел примерно так: it-svalka.ru [слэш] wp-content [слэш]  script_obmen.txt (слэши повставляйте в адрес)